# Relative path to open file while running .app OSX C++

Tags: c++, macos

I've got some issue I cannot solve alone. I have a file I have to open in my program. It works, when I use absolute path from the root directory. When I use the the relative path from the running folder, it doesn't work.

I use OSX. C++ program.

Does not work:

```
filename = "../filefolder/lab.txt";
```

Works:

```
filename = "/Users/Thomas/Documents/Lab/filefolder/lab.txt"
```

The .app is included in `src` directory which is in `Lab` directory - so the `Lab` directory has two folders - `src` and `filefolder`. (Certainly, I use `ifstream myfile` and `myfile.open(filename.c_str())`, when `string filename`).

Thank you for you help guys!

---

EDIT: Now, I've realized it even does not work when the file is in the main directory of the file: `filename = "lab.txt"` or `filename = "./lab.txt"` where lab.txt is included in the same directory as my .app program.